# how to use for loop in html template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

i try to use  for loop in html template to make a table but the probleme he add always column outside the table like in this pic

[image]

i dont know why he continue directly out the table(if ther is one object only it's ok but when ther is more than 1 object in the ligne then this happned)

what can i do ?

thanks

html templates

```
<tr class="col-2">
    <th>JOUR</th>
    <th>8-10</th>
    <th>10-12</th>
    <th>12-14</th>
    <th>14-16</th>
    <th>16-18</th>
</tr>


<tr class="col-2">
    <td>SAMEDI</td>

             {% for ins in ob %}
    {%  if ins.jour = 'S' %}
    {% if ins.heur = '1' and ins.jour = 'S' %} <td>{{ins}}</td> {% else  %} <td>    </td> {% endif %}
    {% if ins.heur = '2' and ins.jour = 'S' %} <td>{{ins}}</td>{% else  %} <td>    </td> {% endif %}
    {% if ins.heur = '3' and ins.jour = 'S' %} <td>{{ins}}</td>{% else  %} <td>    </td> {% endif %}
    {% if ins.heur = '4' and ins.jour = 'S' %} <td>{{ins}}</td>{% else  %} <td>    </td> {% endif %}
    {% if ins.heur = '5' and ins.jour = 'S' %} <td>{{ins}}</td>{% else  %} <td>    </td> {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

 {% if a != 2 %}

     <td></td>
             <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    {% endif %}
</tr>
```

views.py

```
def tempss(request):
ob=temps.objects.all()
a=1
b=1
c=1
d=1
e=1
f=1
for ins in ob:
    if ins.jour=='S':
        a=2
    elif ins.jour=='D':
        b=2
```

model.py

```
class temps(models.Model):
JOUR_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Samedi'),
    ('D', 'Dimanche'),
    ('L', 'Lundi'),
    ('M', 'Mardi'),
    ('R', 'Mercredi'),
    ('J', 'Jeudi'),
    ('V', 'Vendredi'),
)
HEUR_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '8-10'),
    ('2', '10-12'),
    ('3', '12-14'),
    ('4', '14-16'),
    ('5', '16-18'),
)
jour = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=JOUR_CHOICES)
heur = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=HEUR_CHOICES)
salle=models.ForeignKey(salle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
groupe=models.ForeignKey(groupe,on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'any_field':False},)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop

```
{% for ins in ob %}
```

is going to render an empty table data tag for every object where it does not fulfill the conditions you define.

This part is redundant since you already encapsulate with the same condition:

```
and ins.jour = 'S' %}
```

However, the AND makes more sense when you want to create the table (which has a fixed number of rows and cells), and put the conditions into the cells instead - I am sure there is a more elegant solution but given view and model, that's what I came up with:

```
<td>{% for ins in obj %}{% if ins.jour = 'S' and ins.heur = '1' %}{{ins}}
{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
```

Repeat for the rest of the timeslots accordingly.
Maybe consider constructing the table values in the view instead of the template.